# How to center my menu bar with css. (I am using Microsoft Expression Web 4)

Tags: html, css

I am kind of new to html and css. I am having major difficulty in centering my menu bar. Can anyone tell me which tag to grab please?
I had tried to read more posts here and I was unable to solve it, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

<title>Untitled 2</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    background-color: #dfe3ee;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 75%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;

}

#menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    border-top:1 solid #ccc;
    border-left:1 solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1 solid #ccc;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;      
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 8em;
    color:white;
    background-color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background-color: #6666AA;

}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    font-family:"Bookman Old Style"
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul ul {
    display:none;

}

#menu ul li: hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

#menu {
    display:inline-block;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 558px">
<div class="header">
    Cotton
</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul style="width: 699px">
            <li><a href="index.html"><span style="font-family: Impact">Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="collections.html"><span style="font-family: Impact">Our Collections</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html"><span style="font-family: Impact">About Us</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"><span style="font-family: Impact">Contact Us</span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem, but the `border` properties of menu need units, probably px, after the 1.  The CSS validator is your friend: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the inline width of `#menu`, also get rid of the (twice declared) `display:inline-block` and actually define the width of `#menu` specifically in order for `margin: 0 auto` to work. I recalculated the widths in `px` as, to my view, `em` is a pain when trying to calculate those.

**NOTE**: If you specify the width of the wrapper to be 75%, my solution may not work on smaller screens as the total width of all menu items will be larger than the wrapper.

Here is what I came up with:

```css
body {
    background-color: #dfe3ee;
}
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 75%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
#menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 536px;
    height:20px;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 128px;
    color:white;
    background-color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu a:hover {
    background-color: #6666AA;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-family:"Bookman Old Style"
}
#menu li:last-child {
    margin-right:0
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul ul {
    display:none;
}
#menu ul li: hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 558px">
    <div class="header">Cotton</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"><span style="font-family: Impact">Home</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="collections.html"><span style="font-family: Impact">Our Collections</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="about.html"><span style="font-family: Impact">About Us</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"><span style="font-family: Impact">Contact Us</span></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo too, so you can play with it a little more, if you wish: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh3280b9/1/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something...but the menu bar doesn't appear centered at all...Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: maybe you are, considering your answer... :)

Comment: ah, i know what's wrong: both of our solutions will largely depend on screen width. Try both in a larger screen and you'll see what I'm talking about!

Comment: Blah...the curse of previewing code in a small Fiddle window. Good catch. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: Your solution clearly works, but I don't understand the need for an explicit width on `#menu`... shouldn't the browser use the calculated width?

Comment: from my experience, if you don't define it, `margin: 0 auto` will not get you the desired effect of centering the element... sorry, i don't have the book to cite from, it's pure experience... ;)

Comment: I *believe* it ... I tested your solution separately.  I just don't *understand* it.  (Um, might want to put `px` after the 1 in the `border-` properties.)

Comment: @Samer El Sabeh:  Be sure you accept the answer that you find fixes your problem.  Consider upvoting it, too.

Comment: @BobBrown corrected the `px`, thanks for that! apparently i haven't checked everything...

Comment: That worked perfectly!
Thank you webeno. 
One more thing though. I am attempting to move the last <li> in the menu to the right. I tried doing that by grabbing it like this:

li:last-child {}
But that also did not work, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes

**EDIT:**

```css
#menu {
  margin-left: 225px; /*changed*/
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1 solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1 solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1 solid #ccc;
}
    
#menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0; /*not required*/
}
```

also `width: 699px` was removed from `ul`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6uF9/17/embedded/result/)

Comment: I am still having difficulty differentiating between padding and margin

Comment: I just edited my answer. 

When setting borders the margins are not excluded in the content, whereas paddings are included in the content. Hope you got the difference :)

Comment: So the margin moves the actual border with the content, whereas paddings only move the content?

Comment: Right. Here's a visual demonstration : http://www.w3schools.com/css/box-model.gif
You can get a better description here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

By the way, if my answer helped in you in some way you can thank me by upvoting my answer :)

Comment: Yea it has @theScorpion. Unfortunately, it says I need 15 rep to upvote. So as soon as I get them, I shall upvote both the answers as they both were of help to me. Again thank you!